# Chrome fonts look horrible. They appear to have spaces in some of the letters

Tags: x11, fonts, chrome

Using Gentoo and X11. Not using a desktop manager....only X11 and compiz fusion.

My default chrome fonts are horrible. For instance, see the space that is between `proper ty`. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Image from my fonts in browser:
[image]

In the browser dev console it shows the font(s) to be:

`font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue Light,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif;`

Comment: So... which fonts do you have installed in your system? I wouldn't be surprised if you needed to explicitly install any font that may be desirable on a Gentoo system.

Comment: @Ángel https://dpaste.com/35ND9BS6S

Comment: those are not the actual fonts, but fontconfig configuration for specific types of fonts, try running `fc-list`.

Comment: I know this comment isn't helpful, but if you don't mind, why use Chrome (a google product) if you've already went so far into free software to set up and run Gentoo?

Comment: @Ángel Thanks.. https://dpaste.com/ECMW6AVAA